# Is there any way to save Mac OS X preferences into a shell file?

Tags: mac, terminal, macos

Whenever I reinstall my Mac OS and/or buy a new Mac, I have to configure manually almost all the options of mouse, dock, etc.

I'd like to know if Mac OS or some software can provide some way to save all the configurations I set up with the System Preferences app into a shell file, creating something like Mathias Bynens' https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.macos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After many hours finding for something at least useful to my problem, I found a website called [Secrets](http://web.archive.org/web/20150621044359/http://secrets.blacktree.com/), which provides a lot of common Mac OS "defaults write" commands.

Anyway, thank Tony and drfrogsplatless for giving me clarifications and tips that were helpful to me.

(edit: site offline, using archived version)

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20150322005829/http://secrets.blacktree.com/? has an archive copy from September 2015.

Answer (score 14):

The System Preferences appear to be stored in various places, depending on whether they are user or system specific. A lot of them are stored in either `/Library/Preferences/` or `$HOME/Library/Preferences/` (for per-user settings). But each preference pane will have its own way of storing them.

You can see which preferences are stored this way by typing:

```
defaults read <domain>
```

Where `<domain>` is either the start of the filename in your per-user system preferences, or the full path to a `.plist` file. For example:

```
defaults read com.apple.screensaver
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver
```

The former will show your per-user customisation of the screensaver settings, while the latter will show the system screensaver settings.

The settings are largely organised by preference pane, though not necessarily that straight forward. You'll likely have to poke around in `/Library/Preferences` and sub-folders (especially `SystemConfiguration`) to find them all.

One option would be to just copy the relevant files out, and put them back in place for new installations.

Another way would be to export and import it as required.

Exporting the Power Management (Energy Saver) System Preferences to pm.plist:

```
defaults export /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement pm.plist
```

Importing those preferences from `pm.plist` on the new computer:

```
defaults import /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement sysprefs.plist
```

You may even want to edit the various exported `.plist` files if there are specific system preferences you do/don't want to share between computers. That way you can have some customisation locally, and the `import` command will not overwrite those, just add the ones you've set in the `.plist` files. You can use the `defaults` command to modify your own `.plist` files as well (but make sure you specify the full path to the file, not just a name, or you may be modifying your per-user preferences).

Comment: "com.apple.systempreferences" doesn't actually contain any preferences for the System. It contains the preferences for the System Preferences application. So none of the actual configuration you do **with** System Preferences are stored in this file.

Comment: @TonyWilliams, right you are, will fix that up...

Answer (score 10):

Automatically producing a script to make all the required changes is well nigh impossible. Mac system administrators spend many hours in dark bars drinking beer or bourbon and swapping bits of these files - we are reluctant to share all that work unless you are prepared to pick up the tab.

Actually the easiest way to capture the config changes is to use snapshotting.

Grab a copy of [InstallEase](http://www.absolute.com/en/products/installease) and snapshot your new Mac. Now do all the configuration that you want and you can take another snapshot and build an installer that will install the changed files into a new Mac.

Of course complications can arise when applying the changes to a new version of the operating system but that's why we drink the bourbon.

Comment: Is there at least any list with the options for the "defaults write" command?

Comment: No. The defaults command can write to any preference file in the system so it is impossible to provide a full list.

Comment: This is a clever idea.

Comment: InstallEase seems to not be available anymore

Comment: Casper has a snapshotting tool you can use instead of InstallEase.

Answer (score 8):

The last time I did a clean reinstall I just copied the whole `~/Library/Preferences/` folder, and I didn't run into any issues because of it. Settings for old versions of applications and Mac-specific settings should just be ignored. There are almost no files in `~/Library/Preferences/` on a new installation, and if you delete all files in `~/Library/Preferences/`, the preference files will be recreated when they are needed.

The preference files for sandboxed applications are now stored in `~/Library/Containers/`, but I don't know if copying it to another Mac would cause any issues.

You might also just use [Migration Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4889).

Or if you go the `.osx` route, you can diff the output of `defaults read`:

1. Run `defaults read|awk 'length<200'>/tmp/a`
2. Change some settings
3. Run `defaults read|awk 'length<200'>/tmp/b;diff /tmp/[ab]`

You can run `sudo opensnoop` or use [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) to see what files are modified when you change preferences from the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Mackup is what you are looking for. https://github.com/lra/mackup/tree/master/doc

Comment: Mackup looks like an awesome tool but it doesn't support defaults write. Also this explains it better than the link you provided: https://github.com/lra/mackup

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partially completed Apple Script I wrote in August of 2016 for my Mac, posted here as a, well, "proof of concept" is a bit strong, but it's something you can play with:

(*
Before running this script you must first grant Apple Script tights under System Preferences--> Security & Privacy--> Accessibility and allow Apple Script to control the computer. You can get a head start by running the script until it fails at that point. Then stop the script, navigate over to that Preferences dialog, and check the box next to Script Editor. Then you can go back, delete all the screenshots already taken (to avoid confusing duplicates), and start the script again.

Why do you need to do this? Becaues some prefernce dialogs, once opened and "photographed," need to be explicitly closed with a mouse click on the Cancel button. Apple Script can't do that unless it has rights "to control your computer" within that pref.
*)

```
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
delay 0.25

-- MAKE THE PREFS PICS FOLDER ON THE DESKTOP IF IT ISN'T THERE ALREADY.
-- IF IT IS THERE ALREADY, NO CHECKING IS DONE WITH REFERENCE TO WHATEVER FILES ARE IN IT.
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists folder "Prefs Pics" of desktop) then
        make new folder with properties {name:"Prefs Pics", location:"desktop"}
    end if
end tell

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate

-- THE PREFS ARE ORDERED BELOW ALPHABETICALLY. TO HAVE THEM SAVE THAT WAY, REMOVE THE ORDER ID (oid) VARIABLE FROM THE CODE LINE SETTING EACH FILENAME. OTHERWISE THE FILENAME WILL BE SET BASED ON THE GROUP AND ICON NUMBERS (ROW AND COLUMN) AS DISPLAYED WHEN SYSTEM PREFS ARE ARRANGED BY CATEGORY.
-- GROUP 4 NO 3 APP STORE
set oid to 43
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.appstore"
-- Now that the first pref window is up, get its name and assign it to a variable
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
-- Do the same for its ID
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
-- Now wait one second and capture the window, passing the wid varialble to screencapture's -l switch and the nid variable to the filename to be used, and save the file
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"
-- note you can't be messing around with the computer until the script ends; otherwise you'll interfere and prolly capture wrong winders

-- GROUP 4 NO 7 TIME MACHINE
set oid to 47
set current pane to pane "com.apple.prefs.backup"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 3 NO 5 BLUETOOTH
set oid to 35
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.Bluetooth"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 4 NO 5 DATE & TIME
set oid to 45
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.datetime"
reveal anchor "DateTimePref" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "TimeZonePref" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "ClockPref" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 1 NO 2 DESKTOP & SCREEN SAVER                                              -- NEEDS TROUBLESHOOTING TO SELECT LEFT PANE IN DESKTOP TAB
set oid to 12
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.desktopscreeneffect"
-- reveal anchor "DesktopPref" of current pane
-- set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
-- set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
-- do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "ScreenSaverPref" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 2 NO 1 DISPLAYS
set oid to 21
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"
-- reveal anchor "displaysArrangementTab" of current pane                   -- NEEDS TROUBLESHOOTING
-- reveal anchor "displaysColorTab" of current pane                         -- NEEDS TROUBLESHOOTING
-- reveal anchor "displaysGeometryTab" of current pane                      -- NEEDS TROUBLESHOOTING
-- reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab"                                               -- NEEDS TROUBLESHOOTING

-- GROUP 1 NO 3 DOCK
set oid to 13
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.dock"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 2 NO 2 ENERGY SAVER
set oid to 22
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.energysaver"
--  reveal anchor "Schedule" of current pane                                        -- NEEDS TO BE CLOSED BEFORE MOVING ON

-- GROUP 1 NO 4 MISSION CONTROL
set oid to 14
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.expose"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 3 NO 3 EXTENSIONS
set oid to 33
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.extensions"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 1 NO 1 GENERAL
set oid to 11
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.general"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 3 NO 1 ICLOUD  
-- set oid to 31
-- set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.icloud"                  -- THIS PREFERENCE WAS NOT COPIED

-- GROUP 3 NO 2 INTERNET ACCOUNTS
-- set oid to 32
-- set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts"        -- THIS PREFERENCE WAS NOT COPIED

-- GROUP 2 NO 3 KEYBOARD
set oid to 23
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard" -- NEEDS TROUBLESHOOTING
reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Text" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "shortcutsTab" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "InputSources" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "keyboardTab_ModifierKeys" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click button "Cancel" of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"
end tell

-- GROUP 1 NO 5 LANGUAGE & REGTION
set oid to 15
set current pane to pane "com.apple.Localization"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Region" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Language" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 2 NO 4 MOUSE
set oid to 14
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.mouse"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 3 NO 4 NETWORK
--  set oid to 34
--  set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.network"

-- GROUP 1 NO 8 NOTIFICATIONS
-- set oid to 18
-- set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.notifications"

-- GROUP 4 NO 2 PARENTAL CONTROLS
-- set oid to 42
--  set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.parentalcontrols"

-- GROUP 2 NO 6 PRINTERS & SCANNERS
--  set oid to 26   
--  set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.printfax"
-- reveal anchor "fax" of current pane
--  reveal anchor "share" of current pane
--  reveal anchor "print" of current pane
-- reveal anchor "scan" of current pane

-- GROUP 1 NO 6 SECURITY & PRIVACY
set oid to 16
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.security"
reveal anchor "General" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "FDE" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Firewall" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Privacy" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Privacy_LocationServices" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Privacy_Contacts" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Privacy_Calendars" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Privacy_Reminders" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Privacy_Facebook" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Privacy_Accessibility" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Privacy_Diagnostics" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"
--  reveal anchor "Privacy_Twitter" of current pane
--  reveal anchor "Privacy_Weibo" of current pane
--  reveal anchor "Privacy_TencentWeibo"
--  reveal anchor "Privacy_Assistive" of current pane
--  reveal anchor "Privacy_LinkedIn" of current pane
--  reveal anchor "Advanced" of current pane

-- GROUP 3 NO 6 SHARING
set oid to 36
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.sharing"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 2 NO 7 SOUND
set oid to 27
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.sound"
reveal anchor "effects" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "output" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "input" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 4 NO 4 DICTATION & SPEECH
set oid to 44
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.speech"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "TTS" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Dictation" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 1 NO 7 SPOTLIGHT
set oid to 17
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.spotlight"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "privacy" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "searchResults" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 4 NO 6 STARTUP DISK
set oid to 46
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.startupdisk"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 2 NO 5 TRACKPAD
set oid to 25
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.trackpad"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 4 NO 1 USERS & GROUPS
set oid to 41
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.users"
reveal anchor "passwordPref" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "startupItemsPref" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "loginOptionsPref" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

--  reveal anchor "mobilityPref" of current pane
--  set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
--  set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
--  do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

-- GROUP 4 NO 8 ACCESSIBILITY
set oid to 48
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Seeing_VoiceOver" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Switch" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Keyboard" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Seeing_Display" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Hearing" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Seeing_Zoom" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "SpeakableItems" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Media_Descriptions" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Mouse" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"

reveal anchor "Captioning" of current pane
set nid to (get name of first window whose visible is true)
set wid to (get id of first window whose visible is true)
do shell script "screencapture -T1 -l" & wid & " ~/Desktop/Prefs\\ Pics/" & oid & "\\ " & quoted form of (nid) & "\\ " & "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit


-- HELPERS FOR THE HOMEWORK THAT NEEDED TO BE DONE BEFORE THE SCRIPT COULD BE WROTEN
-- GET ALL PANE ID'S
-- tell application "System Events"
-- tell application "System Preferences"
-- get the id of every pane
-- end tell
-- end tell


-- GET ALL PANE NAMES
-- tell application "System Preferences"
-- name of panes
-- end tell


-- GET THE ANCHOR NAME FOR A PARTICULAR PANE
-- tell application "System Preferences"
-- activate
-- get the name of every anchor of pane id "com.apple.preferences.users"
-- end tell
```