# Can I set a specific Time zone for an app in macOS?

Tags: defaults, macos

In macOS, I can use the code below to set specific language for Word.app, can I use some similar code to set a specific Time zone for an app?

```
defaults write com.microsoft.Word AppleLanguages '("de")'
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Background

With standard UNIX CLI tools you can set the environment variable `TZ=<XXX>` with a timezone and any application that runs within the shell where this was done will pick it up and use its value as their timezone.

#### Using TZ

For example, you can use this command to get the complete list of valid values to set `TZ=` to like so:

```
$ sudo systemsetup -listtimezones
```

And here I've listed just the first 10:

```
$ sudo systemsetup -listtimezones | head
Time Zones:
 Africa/Abidjan
 Africa/Accra
 Africa/Addis_Ababa
 Africa/Algiers
 Africa/Asmara
 Africa/Bamako
 Africa/Bangui
 Africa/Banjul
 Africa/Bissau
```

For this example, I'm going to use Tokyo's timezone, so we can find it like this:

```
$ sudo systemsetup -listtimezones | grep -i tokyo
 Asia/Tokyo
```

#### CLI Example

We can see the effect of setting our shell to this like this:

```
# My default timezone, EDT
$ date
Sat Apr 13 22:44:55 EDT 2019

# Using Tokyo's
$ TZ=Asia/Tokyo date
Sun Apr 14 11:44:59 JST 2019
```

#### GUI Example

In my limited testing this same approach works with GUI applications as well. In this example I installed this [application that I found called `the-clock`](https://seense.com/the_clock/).

```
$ brew cask install the-clock
```

Now we can invoke it like this from the shell:

```
$ '/Applications/The Clock.app/Contents/MacOS/The Clock'
```

It looks like this when you run it in the menubar at the top:

[image: ss1]

Now if we invoke it with the environment variable set:

```
$ TZ=Asia/Tokyo '/Applications/The Clock.app/Contents/MacOS/The Clock'
```

And look in the menubar:

[image: ss2]

We can see that the timezone was changed when we invoked the GUI application.

#### What about defaults?

In investigating any methods that you could use with the `defaults` command I didn't find anything compelling that led me to believe that you could do this through the `defaults` as in your example.

These resources led me to believe that you cannot:

- [CHANGE MACOS USER PREFERENCES VIA COMMAND LINE](https://pawelgrzybek.com/change-macos-user-preferences-via-command-line/)
- [Is there any way to save Mac OS X preferences into a shell file?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118482/is-there-any-way-to-save-mac-os-x-preferences-into-a-shell-file)
- [A database of hidden settings for Mac OS X](http://web.archive.org/web/20150318015905/http://secrets.blacktree.com/?show=all)

#### References

- [output from timezone.txt](https://gist.github.com/palaniraja/f8e21e8c66eac7e1b313)